# CakePHP 3 - Change Password

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I began to learn cakephp 3 now, he's beta version so your manual is not complete yet..

I need to change the user's password, but it's triggered the Flash Error. Debugging the variable $user just show "The Field Required" but all table's fields are value NULL.

My Code:

```
 //Create a new Entity
 $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
                    // Set new password and user's id... I'm not doing with session yet, ok?
                    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, ['password' => $this->request->data['new-password'], 'id' => 2]);
                    debug($user->errors());
                    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                        $this->Flash->success('Its Right');
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->error('FAIL');
                    }
```

Debuggin **$user** They are the field of user table.

```
[
    'gym_id' => [
        (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'role_id' => [
        (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'name' => [
        (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'username' => [
        (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'stats' => [
        (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
    ]
]
```

My **UserModel**

```
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
            ->add('gym_id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('gym_id', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('gym_id')
            ->add('role_id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('role_id', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('role_id')
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('name')
            ->requirePresence('username', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('username')
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password')
            ->add('stats', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('stats', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('stats');

        return $validator;
    }
```

SOLVED

According to the documentation the patchEntity was created for you to use the existing entity, creating a new I would be creating a line at the database, then the solution was:

Just update UsersController, use a entity with the a user's id that you want to update

UsersController

```
$user_data = $this->Users
                        ->find()
                        ->where(['id' => 2])
                        ->first();

 $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user_data, 
                        [
                        'password' => $this->request->data['new-password']                        
                        ]);
                    /*debug($user);
                    exit();*/
                    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                        $this->Flash->success('Success, GG EASY');
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->error('FAIL, SurrenderAt20');
                    }
```

Thx everybody ^^

Comment: Try to debug `$this->request->data` and see if returns any value from those required fields.

Comment: It's right, all value are returning  [ 'current-password' => 'çlk', 'new-password' => '1234','confirm-password' => '1234']

Comment: My form are three fields, current-password, new and confirm, i'm doing validation with if clauses and its working, i just to want "edit" password field

Comment: Alright. How is your **UserModel**? 
Could you please Edit your question with this information?
A faced same problem as you on CakePHP 2.5.
Does your Model has a `public $validate` declared?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit, wait a secund please :)

Comment: Does the problem lies in the validation? Why do I create a new entity and the model he sees fields are required?

Comment: Somehow CakePHP uses this validation requiring those fields. I faced this issue when I created edit action in UserController when I had to remove some required fields due to this conflicts.
I suggest you to create another Controller just for changing password like **AlterarSenhaController** and treat this action in it.
The real problem is this conflict required fields from any action you create inside Model. Or you need to remove these validation required field and treat then in JavaScript or **IF** Statement inside Controller

Comment: I'm edit all require's fields to "FALSE" but the problem continue. If i create a new Controller i need create a new model without validation? How will i  procede?

Comment: I tried change "requirePresence" , "create" to "false" but when i use debug, it continue show "'This field is required'" for these fields

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes You might want to look into [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) and a nice and clean behavior driven way to get this done with zero coding on the application part. Out of the box. Both for 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are requiring these fields presence, so that's the expected behavior. As per your comments, setting the second argument of `requirePresence()` to `"false"` won't do anything, as that's a string, if you'd wanted to disable this check you'd have to supply a boolean value, ie `false` without quotes. However this will just mess up your default validation.

That being said, there are various ways to solve the "problem" of fields not always being required, one would be to make use of a separate set of validation rules, something like:

```
public function validationUpdatePassword(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->requirePresence('id')
        // you might want to add some actual password validation here
        ->requirePresence('password')
        ->notEmpty('password');

    return $validator;
}
```

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
    'password' => $this->request->data['new-password'],
    'id' => 2
], [
    'validate' => 'updatePassword'
]);
```

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validating-data-before-building-entities**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html**

Comment: well, it's worked, but instead change password of user id = 2, was created a new id with all field empty and new password

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes Works fine for me, maybe you are using an outdated version where the automated ["_set `isNew()` to `false`_" functionality](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-entities) isn't working properly.